# Error when creating foreign table in GridDB (FDW)

Tags: griddb

I’m getting issue when creating the foreign table. I think `griddb_fdw` can not link table "T 1" to foreign table "ft1".

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE ft1 (
    c0 int,
    "C 1" int NOT NULL,
    c2 int NOT NULL,
    c3 text,
    c4 timestamptz,
    c5 timestamp,
    c6 varchar(10),
    c7 char(10) default 'ft1',
    c8 text
) SERVER griddb_srv;
ALTER FOREIGN TABLE ft1 DROP COLUMN c0;
ALTER FOREIGN TABLE ft1 OPTIONS (table_name 'T 1');
\det+
                    List of foreign tables
 Schema | Table |  Server  |    FDW options     | Description 
--------+-------+----------+--------------------+-------------
 public | ft1   | loopback | (table_name 'T 1') | 
(1 row)

SELECT * FROM ft1;
ERROR:  No such container: ft1
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
connection to server was lost
```

Could you please fix this issue?